# ActiveRecord how to update model with the count of a related 1 to n model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models with a 1 to n relation in between:

> Book 1 <-> n Page

I do want to make a update statement on all Books (about 300'000). The Book model has a column interesting_pages_count, which need's to get summarized out of all Pages which interesting attribute is set to true.

Is this possible in one Statement?

Thanks,
Makrus

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, at least in PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE books SET interesting_pages_count = (
  SELECT count(*) FROM pages WHERE pages.book_id = books.id AND interesting = true
) FROM pages WHERE books.id = pages.book_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with

`Book.update_all({:field => value}, where_condition)`

or with a plain SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, only one statement is really ambitious, but if you define this method on your Book model:

```
def count_interesting_pages
  self.pages.inject(0) { |result, page| result += 1 if page.interesting?}
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
Book.all.each {|b| b.update_attribute(:interesting_pages, count_interesting_pages)}
```